# Create a new_function which has an input n and input_function which return a output_function that does what input_function does n times

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I would like to create a new function that has two inputs (n, input_function) which returns a new output_function that does what input_function does but it does it n times. [Here is the image of what i'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZr7e.png)

```
def repeat_function(n, function, input_number):
    for i in range(n):
        input_number = function(input_number)
    return input_number

def times_three(x):
    return x * 3

print(repeat_function(3, times_three, 10))  #prints 270 so it's correct
print(times_three(times_three(times_three(10))))  #prints 270 so it's correct

#This function does not work
def new_repeat_function(n, function):
    result = lambda x : function(x)
    for i in range(n-1):
        result = lambda x : function(result(x))
    return result

new_function = new_repeat_function(3, times_three)
#I want new_function = lambda x : times_three(times_three(times_three(x))) 
print(new_function(10)) # should return 270 but does not work
```

I tried my best to implement it but it does not work. I need new_repeat_function to do what repeat_function does but instead of returning and integer answer like repeat_function does, new_repeat_function has to return time_three() n times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a function, not the result.

```
def new_repeat_function(n, function):
    def repeat_fn(x):
        result = function(x)
        for i in range(n - 1):
            result = function(result)
        return result

    return repeat_fn
```

Here, you construct a closure that captures the parameters `n` and `function`. Later, when you call the returned closure, it uses `n` and `function` as they were passed to `new_repeat_function`. So, if we call

```
new_func = new_repeat_function(3, three_times)
print(new_func(10))
```

we get 270 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create a `function` that builds another `function`, in python this pattern is called [`decorators`](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), here you have an example:

```
from functools import wraps

def repeated(n):
  def wrapped(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def ret_f(*args, **kwargs):
      res = f(*args, **kwargs)
      for _ in range(1, n):
        res = f(res)
      return res
    return ret_f
  return wrapped

@repeated(2)
def times_three(x):
    return x * 3

print(times_three(10))
```

You can try it [live here](https://repl.it/repls/DarkkhakiEllipticalGraduate)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply recur on `repeat` itself. Ie, you don't need to create a `range` or use a loop at all

```
def repeat (n, f):
  return lambda x: \
    x if n is 0 else repeat (n - 1, f) (f (x))

def times_three (x):
    return x * 3

new_func = repeat (3, times_three)

print (new_func (10))
# 270
```

You can skip intermediate assignments as well

```
print (repeat (0, times_three) (10))
# 10

print (repeat (1, times_three) (10))
# 30

print (repeat (2, times_three) (10))
# 90
```